# How to sum the values of a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, sum, pyspark

I am working in Pyspark and I have a data frame with the following columns.

```
Q1 = spark.read.csv("Q1final.csv",header = True, inferSchema = True)
Q1.printSchema()

root
|-- index_date: integer (nullable = true)
|-- item_id: integer (nullable = true)
|-- item_COICOP_CLASSIFICATION: integer (nullable = true)
|-- item_desc: string (nullable = true)
|-- index_algorithm: integer (nullable = true)
|-- stratum_ind: integer (nullable = true)
|-- item_index: double (nullable = true)
|-- all_gm_index: double (nullable = true)
|-- gm_ra_index: double (nullable = true)
|-- coicop_weight: double (nullable = true)
|-- item_weight: double (nullable = true)
|-- cpih_coicop_weight: double (nullable = true)
```

I need the sum of all the elements in the last column (cpih_coicop_weight) to use as a Double in other parts of my program. How can I do it?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 27):

If you want just a double or int as return, the following function will work:

```
def sum_col(df, col):
    return df.select(F.sum(col)).collect()[0][0]
```

Then

```
sum_col(Q1, 'cpih_coicop_weight')
```

will return the sum.
I am new to pyspark so I am not sure why such a simple method of a column object is not in the library.

Comment: I totally agree with this statement. Why is it necessary to call an empty groupby to get the sum of a column? This function should be the accepted answer (and probably in the library)

Answer (score 10):

try this :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
total = Q1.groupBy().agg(F.sum("cpih_coicop_weight")).collect()
```

In `total`, you should have your result.

Comment: Here `total` is a `[Row(sum(cpih_coicop_weight)=xxx]` if you want to get the actual scalar value you need to `total[0][0]`

Comment: Why this is not one of the default method of dataframe object?

Answer (score 5):

This can also be tried.

```
total = Q1.agg(F.sum("cpih_coicop_weight")).collect()
```